# How to compress tabs in asp.net

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax

I have Asp.net Ajax Tab container. There are so many tabs. Thus I need scroll bar to click tab at the end. Can there be any functionality which compresses the tabs beyond the width of the container and regains after clicking on + sign.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: do you want functionality similar to offered by firefox or chrome for tabs?

Comment: well it will need customization with Ajax tab container and tab control you will have to use javascript alot to achieve this. on the other hand you can use Jquery UI Tabs, its documentation is very good and if you have expertise in jquery it will be a good option.

Comment: @Shoaib Shaikh : Can you give me link which demonstrates this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the official site :
http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/

this is how you can change the looks of tabs

http://keith-wood.name/uiTabs.html

this shows how you can change its code to achieve similar functionality

http://css-tricks.com/jquery-ui-tabs-with-nextprevious/